# RSS Feed Aggregator

Tags: rss, blogs

I'm currently using Google Reader to pull in approximately 100 RSS feed from various types of blogs. Reader then allows me to aggregate all the feeds into one RSS/Atom feed which I can use in third party applications.

Since Google reader is going to shut down on July 1st, does anyone have any recommendations or suggestions? I've tried Yahoo Pipes but it didn't work for all formats.

Note: I'm willing to pay for a service that may offer this so solutions don't need to be free.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use todaynews.info as google alternative.